# Countdown Timer Javascript In Line Code External Scripts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this piece of code online [Countdown Timer](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwNPVq)

And attempted to implement it on a page but it wasn't counting down. Thanks to all who commented. Here's the NOW WORKING sample code (see below snippet)

```js
    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
      var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
      var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
      var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
      };
    }
    
    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
      var clock = document.getElementById(id);
      var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
      var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
      var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
      var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
    
      function updateClock() {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    
        daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
    
        if (t.total <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
      }
    
      updateClock();
      var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
    
    var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
    #clockdiv{
     font-family: sans-serif;
     color: #fff;
     display: inline-block;
     font-weight: 100;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    #clockdiv > div{
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     background: #00BF96;
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #clockdiv div > span{
     padding: 15px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     background: #00816A;
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .smalltext{
     padding-top: 5px;
     font-size: 16px;
    }
```

```html
    
    <div id="clockdiv" align='center'>
      <div>
        <span class="days"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="hours"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="minutes"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="seconds"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Perhaps it needs to do a body onload or I'm missing something because when I try the code it just shows empty boxes and no timer.

While there are many great clock plugins, it makes sense to just do this in raw javascipt as the article says:

code will be lightweight because it will have zero external scripts

website will perform better because you won’t need to load external scripts and style sheets.

have more control because you will have built the clock to behave exactly the way you want it to (rather than trying to bend a plugin to your will).

It seems like a useful piece of code if it could be made to work with minimal changes. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at your browser console to see if there were errors?

Comment: yes it says TypeError clock is Null in Firefox Console

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. Is `#clockDiv` dynamically generated?

Comment: Victor i updated your answer(added snippet) AND IT WORKS FINE. just add script to the bottom of the body, because as you say - the script is unable to find the object hence it could be null. thats the only possible problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If clock is null, then your selector `#clockdiv` is failing. The DOM hasn't been populated yet at the time your script runs: either move the script to the bottom of the body so that the body (including `#clockdiv`) exists before the script runs, or save the script in its own .js file and give it a `defer` attribute, or wrap the whole script in a DOMContentLoaded listener (so it waits for the document to be parsed before running).

Comment: That did it! So always make sure the SCRIPT that is dependent is below the body.

Comment: While putting it at the bottom of `<body>` *works*, it's generally better to separate your HTML and your JS. Scripts aren't content, after all - they're information on *how to interact* with the content, so IMO they semantically belong in the header. `<script src="myscript.js" defer></script>` is easy.

Comment: looks good - any idea on how to center the timer box on the page?

Comment: @Viktor you can use `text-align: center` on the body and `margin: auto` on `#clockdiv` to center on the screen. You could also use `display: flexbox`. Check my answer.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to fix a date in actual time - right now its always timing forward 15 days - the clock would be more useful if the deadline was an actual date - how would you set that ?   var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);  I.e.  Say April 20, 2018

Comment: Right now you have this: `var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);` The 15 in there is where the 15 days are coming from. Alter/multiply as you wish.

Comment: Yes I know the '15' refers to the date. But it's still relative. The script is more useful if its not a relative date but an actual date. What is the syntax for 'var deadline=' for an actual date and time?

Comment: Look up the Date constructor. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

Like @Certain Performance said, you are trying to run your JS before the element has been created. The cleanest solution would be to move your JS to it's own file and include it at the bottom of the body tag.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

#clockdiv {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}

#clockdiv>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #00BF96;
  display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div>span {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #00816A;
  display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Countdown timer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="https://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience and security.</p>
        <![endif]-->

  <h1>Stack Overflow Countdown timer.</h1>

  <div id="clockdiv" align='center'>
    <div>
      <span class="days"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="hours"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="minutes"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="seconds"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Run at the end of the page -->
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are trying to get the DOM element using document.getElementById function before the DOM object was created.
Either you move the script code at the bottom of the code or call initializeClock function in DOMContentLoaded or body load or document load or window load event function.